# Cannot drop index because of foreign key constraint enforcement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

I can't drop an index because some tables used it for foreign key

> Msg 3723, Level 16, State 6, Line 1 An explicit DROP INDEX is not
> allowed on index 'tbl1.ix_cox'. It is being used for FOREIGN KEY
> constraint enforcement.

I tried to disable the index first before dropping

```
ALTER INDEX ix_cox On tbl1
DISABLE
Go
```

But still don't able to drop it.

Do I really need to remove the foreign key on those tables that used that index? Because it is about 30 tables.

Comment: Your index was created to optimize and enforce either a primary key or a unique key. Foreign keys from another tables that relate to these columns can be created beacuse the existance of this primary key or unique states that the column values are unique and correctly identifies 1 row from the table. Dropping the index would break this consistency, so you have no other choice than dropping the related foreign keys first and then the index. You won't be able to re-create the other foreign keys until you stablish another primary key or unique for this same reason.

Comment: A little late, but see my vwFK view below to easily generate the script needed to handle a large number of tables referencing a foreign key.

Comment: The answer to this may help with finding where all the foreign keys are (if you're not sure) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707037/how-to-find-what-foreign-key-references-an-index-on-table

Answer (score 40):

You'll get the same exception if the index was created defining a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

In that case the simple solution is to use the ALTER-TABLE-command instead:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 DROP CONSTRAINT ix_cox
```

Comment: Solved it for #MeToo !

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is the only option you have. you have to drop all foreign key constraints referencing to table and also you cannot recreate the foreign key constraints until you specify another unique index on the table from where you removed index.

Answer (score 2):

Good day,

Here is a full example:

#### Let's create the tables and insert some sample data first

```
use tempdb
GO

-- NOTE! 
--    This sample code presents a POOR CODING where the user
--    does not explicitly named the objects
--    or explicitly create CLUSTERED INDEX

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Users_tbl;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Categories_tbl;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Categories_tbl(
    CategoryID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , CategoryName NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO 
-- find the CLUSTERED INDEX created automatically for us
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Categories_tbl')
GO
-- you can notice that by default the PRIMARY KEY become CLUSTERED INDEX
-- If we did not configure a different CLUSTERED INDEX
-- In my case the automatic name was: PK__Categori__19093A2BAE0EA4C3

-- Let's create the secondary table
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users_tbl(
    UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , UserName NVARCHAR(100)
    , CategoryID INT
    , FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID) REFERENCES Categories_tbl(CategoryID)
)
GO 

-- Insert sample data
INSERT Categories_tbl (CategoryName) VALUES ('a'),('b')
GO
INSERT Users_tbl(UserName,CategoryID)
    VALUES ('a',1),('b',1)
GO

SELECT * FROM Categories_tbl
SELECT * FROM Users_tbl
GO
```

#### REMOVE CLUSTERED INDEX from PRIMARY KEY

If we will try to DROP INDEX of the PK then we will get this error:

> An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index... It is being used for PRIMARY KEY constraint enforcement.

The solution is to drop the FK, Drop the PK, Create new PK with NONCLUSTERED index instead of CLUSTERED, and create the FK

```
/************************************************  */
/********* REMOVE CLUSTERED INDEX from PRIMARY KEY */
/************************************************  */
------------------------------------------------------ 
-- Step 1: DROP the CONSTRAINTs
------------------------------------------------------ 
---- Get FOREIGN KEY name
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(f.constraint_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns f
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes p ON p.object_id = f.referenced_object_id
    WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID('Categories_tbl')
GO

-- DROP FOREIGN KEY
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users_tbl   
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK__Users_tbl__Categ__59063A47 -- Use the name we found above
GO

---- Get PRIMARY KEY name
SELECT name FROM sys.indexes
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('Categories_tbl')
GO
-- DROP PRIMARY KEY
ALTER TABLE dbo.Categories_tbl
    DROP CONSTRAINT PK__Categori__19093A2B9F118674 -- Use the name we found above
GO


------------------------------------------------------ 
-- Step 2: CREATE new CONSTRAINTs
------------------------------------------------------ 
-- And now we can create new PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
--   Since we use PRIMARY KEY We need to have index,
--   but we do not have to use CLUSTERED INDEX
--   we can have NONCLUSTERED INDEX
ALTER TABLE dbo.Categories_tbl
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CategoryID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (CategoryID);
GO
-- Finaly we can create the 
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users_tbl
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Categories_tbl 
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryID)     
    REFERENCES dbo.Categories_tbl(CategoryID)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have an FK on 30 tables like EzLo, it would sure be nice to have some automation. The script in the last two columns of this view will drop and re-add ***all your FK's*** at once:

```
CREATE VIEW vwFK
AS
    select *, addFK = 'ALTER TABLE '+FKtable+' WITH ' + case when is_not_trusted = 1 then 'NO' else '' end + 'CHECK'
                        + ' ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_'+FKtbl+'_'+PKtbl+'] FOREIGN KEY ('+FKcol+') '
                        + ' REFERENCES '+PKtable+' ('+PKcol+')'+' ON UPDATE '+onUpdate+' ON DELETE '+onDelete
                        + case when is_not_for_replication = 1 then ' NOT FOR REPLICATION' else '' end + ';'
                        + case when is_disabled = 1 then '  ALTER TABLE '+FKtable+' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_'+FKtbl+'_'+PKtbl+'];' else '' end
        ,dropFK = 'ALTER TABLE '+FKtable+' DROP ['+FK+'];'
    from (
        select
             PKtable    = object_schema_name(f.referenced_object_id)+'.'+object_name(f.referenced_object_id)
            ,PKtbl      = object_name(f.referenced_object_id)
            ,PKcol      = pc.name
            ,FKtable    = object_schema_name(f.parent_object_id)+'.'+object_name(f.parent_object_id)
            ,FKtbl      = object_name(f.parent_object_id)
            ,colseq     = fk.constraint_column_id
            ,FKcol      = fc.name
            ,FK         = object_name(f.object_id)
            ,onUpdate   = replace(f.update_referential_action_desc collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, '_', ' ')
            ,onDelete   = replace(f.delete_referential_action_desc collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, '_', ' ')
            ,f.is_disabled
            ,f.is_not_trusted
            ,f.is_not_for_replication
        from sys.foreign_key_columns as fk
        join sys.foreign_keys f on fk.constraint_object_id = f.object_id
        join sys.columns as fc on f.parent_object_id = fc.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = fc.column_id
        join sys.columns as pc on f.referenced_object_id = pc.object_id and fk.referenced_column_id = pc.column_id
    ) t
```

Then, something like `select * from vwFK where FKtbl = 'tbl1'`

No guarantees, but this has saved me a *lot* of work over the years. **Just remember to save the addFK statements before running your dropFK's!**

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the FK constraint for temporary being -> drop the index -> re-enable the constraint back like

```
ALTER TABLE your_fk_table NOCHECK CONSTRAINT constraint_name

drop index ids_name

ALTER TABLE your_fk_table CHECK CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

Comment: Same error for me, even with nocheck on the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this script solved this constraint enforcement:

```
ALTER TABLE [table2] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_table1_table_2]

DROP INDEX [ix1] ON [table1]

ALTER TABLE [table2]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_table1_table_2] FOREIGN KEY([id])
REFERENCES [table1] ([id])

ALTER TABLE [table2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_table1_table_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've found that FKs from other tables are referencing my UNUQUIE index instead of PK. To solve this I've found very helpful SP:

```
exec sp_fkeys MyTableWithUniqueIndex
```

There is a column PK_NAME in results that clearly shows that some FK are not referencing PK in table, but the index I want to delete:
[image: Screenshot]

So solution of the issue is to fix FK to reference PK:

```
-- drop FK constraints that reference the index
ALTER TABLE OtherTableWithFK DROP CONSTRAINT FK_dbo.OtherTableWithFK_dbo.MyTableWithUniqueIndex_FKId
-- same for all other FK that reference the index

DROP INDEX IX_Id ON MyTableWithUniqueIndex;

-- add all removed FK constraints back
ALTER TABLE OtherTableWithFK WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_dbo.OtherTableWithFK_dbo.MyTableWithUniqueIndex_FKId FOREIGN KEY(FKId)
REFERENCES MyTableWithUniqueIndex (Id)
-- same for all other FK that reference the index
```